# How to multiply an observation by the previous observation but only if a certain condition is true

Tags: r, for-loop

I have data that includes the variables start and weight. I would like to create a new weight that multiples the original weight by the previous weight, and then take this newly created weight and multiply this by the previous weight, so on and so on until the end of the data set. I only would like these new weights to be calculated for all observations where start is greater than 0.

```
start<-c(0,1,2,3,4,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1)
weight<-c(1.427,1.073,1.074,1.074,15.004,1.428,1.073,1.439,1.074,1.416,1.463,1.439,1.074,1.439,1.451)
data<-as.data.frame(cbind(start,weight))
```

The code I have so far to run the for loop:

```
for (i in 1:4){
data$new_weight<-ifelse(data$start==i, data$weight * shift(data$weight, 1L, type="lag"), data$weight)
}
```

Ending up with this dataframe:

```
new_weight<-c(1.427,1.531,1.645,1.766,26.496,1.428,1.531,1.439,1.546,1.416,1.463,1.439,1.546,1.439,1.451)
data<-cbind(data, new_weight)
data
```

Comment: But your `for` looop is not giving the expected right?

Comment: Si the expected 'new_weight' correct?

Comment: Correct, my for-loop isn't giving the correct new weight. That is the part I need help with.

Comment: What is the expected output.  I have a feeling that 'new_weight' is not correct

Comment: Can you please check the last few values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, this helps

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% 
    group_by(grp = cumsum(start == 0)) %>%
    mutate(weight = cumprod(weight)) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-grp)
```